# How can I get Redirect to work on Electron?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a desktop application using Electron. But, i can't seem to get Redirect working to separate HTML files. The following is the code that I currently have :-

```
if (inUserV.value = user_id || username) { 
                    profileWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 800, autoHideMenuBar: true, resizable: false});
                    add("Browser Window Created");

                    profileWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');
                    add("");

                    profileWindow.show();
                    add(username + " " + user_id)
                }
```